# Performing compound query in firestore to fetch by dates

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a query to fetch between two dates. The date it was created and the date that the user inputed.
There is that issue with compounded queries which won't work with the logic I attempted at first:

```
const filtered = await firestore()
      .collection('receitas')
      .where('id', '==', userInfo?.id)
      .where(
         firestore.Filter.and(
           firestore.Filter('dataReceita', '<', dataReceitaFim),
           firestore.Filter('dataReceita', '>=', dataReceitaInicio),
           firestore.Filter('dataUpload', '<', dataUploadInicio),
           firestore.Filter('dataUpload', '>=', dataUploadFim),
         ),
       )
      .get()
      .then((documentSnapshot) => {
        const data = documentSnapshot.docs.map((receita) => {
          return receita.data()
        })
        return data
      })
```

These are the values from the variables:

```
    const dataReceitaInicio = filter.dataReceita
      ? new Date(filter.dataReceita)
      : new Date('1900-00-00')
    const dataUploadInicio = filter.dataUpload
      ? new Date(filter.dataUpload)
      : new Date('1900-00-00')
    const dataReceitaFim = filter.dataReceitaFim
      ? new Date(filter.dataReceitaFim)
      : new Date(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
    const dataUploadFim = filter.dataUploadFim
      ? new Date(filter.dataUploadFim)
      : new Date(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

So I made some searches and came across this solution (https://levelup.gitconnected.com/firestore-query-limitations-and-how-to-work-around-them-e058a844ae57) which did not return me nothing:

```
const filtered = await firestore()
      .collection('receitas')
      .where('id', '==', userInfo?.id)
      .orderBy('dataReceita')
      .orderBy('dataUpload')
      .startAt([dataReceitaInicio, dataUploadInicio])
      .endAt([dataReceitaFim, dataUploadFim])
      .get()
      .then((documentSnapshot) => {
        const data = documentSnapshot.docs.map((receita) => {
          return receita.data()
        })
        return data
      })
```

Or if possible perform something like the following:

```
firestore.Filter(['dataReceita', 'dataUpload'], '<', [dataReceitaFim, dataUploadFim]),
```

With the above solution, if I use one orderBy, it will work, although with 2 it won't
My indexes:

[image]

But this query is not returning nothing, what can I perform to get the result I wish?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

All range/inequality filters in a Firestore query have to be on the same field at the moment. Firestore doesn't support queries with `>` or `<` conditions on multiple fields.

---

Since the query you're trying to perform is not supported, the best you can do on Firestore is to perform one of the range condition on the database, and the other condition(s) in your application code.

If that is not acceptable for your app, consider using a database that better matches your querying needs.

Comment: Does using firestore functions can fix this issue?

Comment: The query capabilities and limitations are determined by Firestore and not by the SDK, so using a different SDK/platform makes no difference.